# Custom Route in Resource Controller

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to build a CMS in Laravel 5.8 but got stuck in creating a custom route for my resource controller. I had used below code to try to achive this:

```
Route::post('/photo-gallery/status', 'backend\Photogallery@updStatus')->name('photo.status'); 
Route::resource('/photo-gallery', 'backend\Photogallery');
```

Reloading the page gives me error as **Route [photo.status] not defined**.

So, I cleared my route cache and tried to list my routes but got below error in terminal as **ReflectionException : Class App\Http\Controllers\Users does not exist**

My Users controller class is at this location "App\Http\Controllers\backend".

```
//Auth::routes();
```

If the above route is uncommented, all the pages works fine but the route list method is not working. So, I just commented this route to check and voila things worked.

My index page gets loaded without any error. But things took an ugly turn when I tried posting the form using ajax to this custom route page. The form is getting **posted to my update method and not updStatus method**. To resolve this issue, I modified the custom route method from POST to PUT but not worked. So i reverted back the route method to POST and now i'm back to square one with same error "ReflectionException : Class App\Http\Controllers\Users does not exist" in terminal and " Route [photo.status] not defined." though **"Auth::routes();" is still being commented**

Below are the complete codes

Routes:

```
//Auth::routes();
Route::group(['as'=>'cms.'  ,'prefix'=>'cms'],function(){
    Route::get('/login', 'backend\Login@index')->name('login');
    Route::post('/login', 'backend\Login@doLogin')->name('login.do');
    Route::any('/logout', 'backend\Logout@index')->name('logout');
    Route::get('/', 'backend\Dashboard@index')->name('dashboard');
    Route::resource('/user-management', 'backend\Users');
    Route::resource('/menu-parent', 'backend\Menumanagement');
    Route::resource('/menu-child', 'backend\Submenumanagement');
    Route::resource('/privilege-management', 'backend\Privileges');

    Route::post('/photo-gallery/status', 'backend\Photogallery@updStatus')->name('photo.status'); 
    Route::resource('/photo-gallery', 'backend\Photogallery');
});
```

Users controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\backend;

class Users extends Controller{
  ... other codes here
}
```

Photogallery Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\backend;
use Auth;

class Photogallery extends Controller
{
      // CUSTOM RESOURCE FUNCTIONS STARTS
      public function updStatus($request)
      {
      // THE AJAX FORM WILL BE POSTED HERE
      }
}
```

index.blade.php

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
      });

    $('.toggle-class').change(function() {
          var status = $(this).prop('checked') == true ? 1 : 0; 
          var rec_id = $(this).data('id'); 

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "{{ route('photo.status') }}",
            data: {'newStatus': status, 'recordId': rec_id, '_method': 'PUT'},
            success: function(response){
              console.log(response)
            }
          });
     });
```

I hope I'm able to explain the issues which I'm facing. Can anyone help me in all this?

Much Regards,

Javed

Comment: composer dumpauto

Comment: is your named route listed in php artisan route:list

Comment: Hello bhucho, running route:list command gives error as "ReflectionException : Class App\Http\Controllers\Users does not exist"

Comment: Hello Vikas, running compose dumpauto installed few packages and gave me "Package manifest generated successfully." message. Post this i started my project and it still gives me error as "Route [photo.status] not defined."